# Using PHP how to pass variables securely between scripts on different servers

Tags: php, authentication

I have a login form on one server, server A. Hosted on another server, server B, I have a script to check the data and return the result. Server B sends the result to server A, but I don't want to pass the result back in the URL or headers with various redirects, because people can spoof a "true/false" to change the result of the login.

e.g.

[image]

I can't use HTTPS/SSL as my web host does not support it for free.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an ssh tunnel between the servers and have the web server on B listen only on localhost:Bs_tunnel_port, while A connects to its localhost:As_tunnel_port.

Or get that SSL thing going... ;)

Comment: did consider it, but I cant use ssl, web host dos not support it for free unfortunately :/

Comment: An ssh tunnel might still work if you have enough permissions to set it up. Has nothing to do with ssl. But your environment seems a bit restricted, so maybe that's also not an option.

Comment: Also, im planning on making this into an api (like how you can login to a site with facebook for example) so "Server A" scripts will be on multiple sites that want to verify their users by calling my check.php